# Group values by two conditions with mixed values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list with the following values:

```
  <event>
    <value1>2013-05-04 10:00:00.123Z</value1>
    <value2>1111</value2>
    <value3>303533F1700DEE80001E8482</value3>
    <value4>IN</value4>
  </event> 

  <event>
    <value1>2013-05-04 10:00:00.123Z</value1>
    <value2>1111</value2>
    <value3>303533F1700DEE80001E8482</value3>
    <value4>OUT</value4>
  </event>
```

I need to group the **value3** values and get the **Distincts** value4.

The difficulty is that its can come mixed, with the the value4 such: "OUT, OUT, IN, OUT, IN, IN".

Is this possible to do in Linq?!

I got this so far:

```
 var s = (from p in trackingList
                group p by new {p.value3}
                into grp
                select new TrackingSteps
                    {
                        DateIn = **grp.Key.value1**,
                        DateOut = 'the **value1** of **value4**'

                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Trying to understand what you're attempting. Are you trying, for each distinct value3, to produce a single object that has properties DateIn and DateOut? Or will you be producing multiple objects for each value3?

Comment: Hi @MichaelGunter, yes I am trying to produce a single object with these props! You got the point!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This LINQ query groups by Value3 and select distinct Value4 for each group

```
var result = trackingList.Descendants("event")
            .Select(E => new { Value1 = E.Element("value1").Value,
                               Value3 = E.Element("value3").Value, 
                               Value4 = E.Element("value4").Value })
            .GroupBy(g => g.Value3)
            .Select(g => new { 
                 Value3 = g.Key, 
                 //DistintValue4 = g.Select(x => x.Value4).Distinct(),
                 DateIn = g.Where(x => x.Value4 == "IN").Select(x => x.Value1).FirstOrDefault(),
                 DateOut = g.Where(x => x.Value4 == "OUT").Select(x => x.Value1).FirstOrDefault()
             });
```

Comment: I guess I've been sad on my Value3 attribution, that's need to be the Value1 (datetime) and the DistinctValue4 need to be the Value1 of the second distict value, quite hard to explain.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question and comment correctly. It would be helpful if you give a sample output. But to get second distinct value you ll use DistintValue4 = g.Select(x => x.Value4).Distinct().ElementAt(1).

Comment: Each object need to output like this below:

- DateIn: Value1 of the IN (grouped by value3)
- DateOut: Value1 of the Out (grouped by value3)

Got it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to attempt an answer, but it's not entirely clear what you're going for. If you are attempting to take a set of objects and produce a single object for each value3, where each of the produced objects has properties DateIn = (MIN value1 where value4 = "IN") and DateOut = (MAX value1 where value4 = "OUT"), then it might look something like this:

```
from p in trackingList
group p by p.Value3 into g
select new {
               Value3 = g.Key,
               DateIn = g.Where(o => o.Value4 == "IN")
                         .Select(o => o.Value1)
                         .DefaultIfEmpty(DateTime.MinValue)
                         .Min(),
               DateOut = g.Where(o => o.Value4 == "OUT")
                          .Select(o => o.Value1)
                          .DefaultIfEmpty(DateTime.MaxValue)
                          .Max()
           }
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I give the trophy to @roughnex cuz he attempted first.

Comment: No problem. Still some issues with both his and my solutions. Also, it seems to me that what you need is still more complex. I would think that if you have "records" like this ... {303533F1700DEE80001E8482, IN, 5PM}, {303533F1700DEE80001E8482, OUT, 5:10PM}, {303533F1700DEE80001E8482, IN, 6PM}, {303533F1700DEE80001E8482, OUT, 7PM} ... you'd want to produce two objects, not just one.

Comment: If I am correct about what you're looking for, please post a new question or unmark the answer from this one. The solution to the problem I outlined in the comment above would be considerably more complex because it would have to correlate objects in the enumerable in a more complex way than can be performed with a simple GroupBy.

Comment: Thanks for all your support on this!